# Video Recording from a DVR using EMGU or DirectShow C#

Tags: video, opencv, directshow, emgucv

I'm in need of recording video from a 4 channel DVR from .net C#. I've looked at EMGU a Opencv .net wrapper as well as the DirectShow .net library to do this. I've decided to give EMGU a go and is quite happy with it when using webcams. Now I want to use a 4 channel H.264 Usb DVR for the same purpose, but I don't know how to select a video channel on the DVR. When running the sample capture application of EMGU I only get a black screen. I have the same problem with DirectShow. It picks up the DVR as a DR 3101_3104 Video Capture device, but is also showing me the black screen.
Note that the camera is working fine, when I use "SuperDVR"(software that came included with the DVR).

I think there must be a way to specify the channel of which camera you want in both of these libraries, but I have no idea. Could someone shed some light on my problem please.

Answer (score 0):

Standard DriectShow way of switching input channels on a DirectShow device is [`IAMCrossbar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd389171%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) interface. Some vendors make it non-standard way though.

You can use `AMCap` sample/tool (it comes with C++ source, and DirectShow.NET has respective definitions as well) from Windows SDK to see if there is a crossbar available for your device, and if so - you will be able to switch inputs this way. Otherwise you need to contact hardware vendor with this question.

[image]

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your reply. I have run AMCap and here is what I'm getting:  ![Valid XHTML](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/818/crossbar.gif).

Comment: So you have [one input only](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/818/crossbar.gif/) there? It seems that you won't be able to switch standard way.

Comment: Yeah. So you think I should contact the hardware vendor?.  On a sidenote, I have to learn this mini-Markdown formatting thing on this site.

Comment: I think so. They might offer updated drivers, sample code, SDK etc.

Comment: Could someone maybe suggest a usb multichannel DVR that will work with Directshow or preferably OpenCV